# displaying animation like :hover:before when the page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I want to output a heading with a style like this. >      https://jsfiddle.net/nakrys29/5/

```
h1:before {
  //code
}

h1:after {
  //code
}
h1:hover:before, h1:hover:after {
  //code
}
```

i  want to display this animation automatically, not just when it is hovered. So this animation should  start automatically when the page is fully loaded but i couldnt work this out. I tried to use js and jquery, but im kind of new to it so i couldnt find the correct method for this

Any help is appreciated

Comment: i guess you can try *CSS3 Keyframes*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a class with the `:before` and `:after` selectors set to `width: 100%` (instead of the `:hover` selector) to be added when the window loads.

```css
h1 {
 position: relative;
 padding: 5px 0;
 background: none;
 border: none;
  width: 40%;
}

h1:before {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 height: 3px;
 width: 0;
 background-color: violet;
 transition: 2s ease all;
}

h1:after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 height: 3px;
 width: 0;
 background-color: violet;
 transition: 2s ease all;
}

.animate:before, .animate:after {
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="textToAnimate">Hello</h1>
<script>
window.onload = function(){
document.getElementById("textToAnimate").classList.add("animate");
}
</script>
```